# Solr 8.5 facet pivot not working as expected

Tags: solr, pivot, facet

How can get only targa that have all idTelecamera set in my fq?

tried this

q=*:*

fq=idTelecamera:(55 115 56)

raw query parameters= facet=true&facet.pivot=targa,idTelecamera

result in image
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlWia.png)

Comment: Do you mean that you want your `fq` to only include those that have all the values? `fq=idTelecamera:(55 AND 115 AND 56)`? Also please try to avoid having images with important data, as they're not searchable, are bad for accessibility, can't be copy and pasted from easily, and requires the reader to navigate back and forth between the image and the question.

Comment: thank you for the advice, i mean exactly that but, if put this fq=idTelecamera:(55 AND 115 AND 56) the results are 0 because field idTelecamera have only one value per document. sorry for my bad english.  shortly i wnat to group my facet by targa but only if it got as idTelecamera as my OR condition in fq

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're looking for in that case - if you use the `fq` as you've given, the only documents included in the facet are those that have either of those ids. Which of the documents in your example shouldn't be included?

Comment: in my case the facet shows a result with only 2 condition of the fq and not all 3 example:
"field":"targa",
          "value":"CH881XW",
          "count":78,
          "pivot":[{
              "field":"idTelecamera",
              "value":115,
              "count":60},
            {
              "field":"idTelecamera",
              "value":55,
              "count":18}]},
in this case is missing the idTelecamera 56 so i dont want to have this results showed

Comment: So your goal is to only include parent pivot variants that have all the given sub types? I'm not sure if you can do that with a pivot facet, since they work on the values given in the documents being returned, and does not apply any custom filtering outside of that (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know it is not possible to do this with Solr facets. A solution could be to create a second collection where you store for each new document the following fields:

- `targa`
- a multivalued `idsTelecamera` field containing the list of telecamera ids related to your `targa`

At this point you can simply filter documents with:
`fq=idTelecamera:(55 AND 115 AND 56)`